# Proof of convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

I want to prove that a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$, if we have the following condition for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$:
$$(1-\epsilon)Y_n \le X_n \le (1+\epsilon)Z_n$$
with $Y_n,Z_n \overset d\longrightarrow N(0,1)$.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean for *all* $\epsilon>0$ or just for a particular one?

Comment: $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, therefore proving it for a particular one would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will rather write $Y_{n,\varepsilon}$ and $Z_{n,\varepsilon}$ in order to make appear the crucial dependence on $\varepsilon$. The letter $N$ denotes a random variable whose distribution is standard normal.

Fix $t\in\mathbb R$. Then for each $n$, $\varepsilon$, 
$$\mu\{X_n\leqslant t\}\leqslant \mu\{(1-\varepsilon)Y_{n,\varepsilon}\leqslant t\},$$
hence for each fixed $\varepsilon$.
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\mu\{X_n\leqslant t\}\leqslant \mu\{(1-\varepsilon)N\leqslant t\}.$$
Since $(1-\varepsilon_k)Y\to Y$ almost surely when $\varepsilon_k\to 0$, we have, 
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\mu\{X_n\leqslant t\}\leqslant \mu\{N\leqslant t\}.$$
Similarly, using the other inequality, we get 
 $$\liminf_{n\to \infty}\mu\{X_n\leqslant t\}\geqslant \mu\{N\leqslant t\}.$$